# C# Using strongly typed dataset tableadapter in data entry forms

Tags: c#, forms, tableadapter

I am writing a database using a strongly typed dataset as windows forms project in C#. The database has one main form and a series of data entry forms (dialogs). I would like to update my disconnected SQL server database once the data entry form has been filled in using the tableadapter.update method directly from the data entry dialogs. I am unsure of the most robust solution to this problem. Some options I have considered are as follows.

1. Use a dialog.Ok returned from data entry form to signal the main form to call table tableadapter.update.
2. Pass the relevant table adapter in the dialog form constructor and call the update method from the dialog form.
3. Set a property on the dialog form that sets the table adapter to be used for updating form the dialog form.
4. Write a public method on the main form that calls tableadpter.update and call this method from the data entry dialogs.

With so many options I am curious to know what others have done, and what unseen pitfalls may exist in each of the possibilities that I have considered.

Having searched extensively for a solution, I am unable to find any widly accepted solutions to using tableadapter.update in another form.

I understand that I could drag and drop a tableadapter to my dialog froms but would prefer not to do this as they are already created in the main form.

Answer (score 0):

in my experience, the Single Responsibility Principle is a good one, and would fit here nicely.

If you are displaying a Form that a user will enter values for Creation/Edit/Deletion etc. I would have that Form perform the required function entirely by itself.

So, if a user clicks 'Save' or 'OK' in the Dialog that they have made the changes in, I would have that Form perform the update to the Database. That way, if there are validation issues etc. they are handled within the Form that the user is currently on.

Once the update is successful, I would then close the Dialog, and update the Main Form's view (if applicable).

Comment: Thanks Steve, I agree this principle would fit nicely but how should I pass the table adapter to the dialog form? What method would be most robust / professional?

Comment: Hi ReefKnot, not seeing your design and code, I would suggest having the Dialog Form take a parameter for the record it will interact with, it will have its own TableAdapter for the data as needed. That way, the Dialog is standalone, will open an editable view of the data that it needs to edit, perform its task, and close. If the data edited is still viewable on the Main Form, then a refresh of that data would then be called for. If there were no changes, was cancelled, or an error, then there would be no need to refresh the Main Form's data. Hope that gives you a bit more to go on...